# How to customize Payment Address form input fileds Opencart 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, twig, opencart, opencart-3

Actually I want to get the values of each inputs using `onfocuson` function on the checkout page under Payment Address section.

Here is screenshot:

[image: Payment Form]

I tried to add document ready function and tried to get the value using each input id but its is not getting.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#payment_address_firstname").focusout(function(){
var firstname = $('#payment_address_firstname').val();
    alert(firstname );
  });
});
```

I am expecting value of the input but I am getting nothing.

Comment: You're missing `#` here: `var firstname = $('payment_address_firstname').val();`

Comment: oh actually it is missed here not on actual code but still not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved that issue by myself I put that code at the end of the page like in footer and under window.load function. Thanks anyways